# Advanced Custom Fields - Text inputs not full height

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-admin

Has anyone ever experienced this issue with WordPress plugin Advanced Custom Fields version 4.4.12:

[image: Text Fields not fully visible]

I've reinstalled the plugin and this has not helped. Also disabled any plugins that have been updated recently and this still hasn't fixed the issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

WordPress Version 4.9.5

Comment: Have you inspected the elements, to see which CSS is causing this? This might help you to see which plugin is overwriting the CSS?

Comment: After closer investigation I can see what plugin has updated and caused this issue. When I disabled the plugin it didn't have any effect. Stripe plugin is the cause and it's caused me no end of issues on the frontend and backend. Thanks :)